# List of financial derivatives Ito's Lemma does not apply

Tags: stochastic-processes, derivatives

According to [Ito's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D%27s_lemma) there is no restriction on the continuity of the stochastic process. The restrictions are on the continuity of the pay-off so that second derivatives with respect to underlying exists.

What are the list of financial instruments where their evolution (derivative) cannot be explained by Ito's Lemma? I have thought about barrier but the PV of those options are also continuous.

Comment: I you talking about vanillas ? In the OTC case you can construct whaterver you want and thus you are free in your choice of pay-off function $f(X_T)$- meaning that $f$ can be easily designed to not fit the conditions of Itô's Lemma

Comment: Please give an example real trade that we cannot use Ito. Here I believe one considers the value of the derivative from initiation to final time point. Thus discontinuity at maturity does not make application of Ito inappropriate

Comment: okey perhaps I am just misundersting you and would like to understand you queston correctly :) - could you thus please explain what it is exactly that you mean by "Applying Ito's Lemma to a financial instrument" ? - are you talking about something like Feyman-Kac where the Lemma is used in the proof ?

Comment: where $df(X_t)$ is not following Ito diffusion process

Comment: perhaps I am still confused but in the case of a payment just at maturity this will already be the case. If $f(X_t,t)$ the payoutfuction than for any plain vanilla option set $f(X_t,t)=0 \forall t<T$ and $f(X_T,T)=(X_T-K)^+$. Obviosuly $f(X_t,t)$ isn't even continuous and neither differentiable everwhere on the compact interval $[0,T]$

Comment: or are you actually interested in the price-function $g(x,t)=E[f(X_T)|X_t=x]$ and $g(X_t,t)$ being an Itô-Diffusion ?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. If the underlying dynamics of $X_t$ contain a discontinuous part, then $f(X_t,t)$ will also be discontinuous in general; even when $f$ is a smooth function.

Comment: @pbr142 I think he assumes $X_t$ to be an Itô-Diffusion otherwise there question would indeed make no sense. Good point pbr142 ^^

Comment: @pbr142 There is a version of the Ito process for the discontinuous stochastic processes. Yes the question is about the price of a derivative, not the final payoff. The discontinuity in the final payoff does not limit the application of Ito derivatives to figure out the price of an option.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the question, but what about American options? Their prices cannot be derived through an application of Ito

Comment: American, ok. Can you explain why prices cannot be following a process derived through Ito? It is not clear to me which underlying Ito assumption is broken by the early exercise

Comment: @adam see answer

Answer (score 1):

adam I still think that your question is a bit vague but perhaps the following will be of some help to you.

First of all Itô's theorem is a tool. It will never give you the price by itself. While working out the concrete formula one might end up using it in one context or another.

In case of a european option, a borel measurable function $h$ and $X_t$ being an Itô Process one has 
$$g(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[h(X_T)|X_t=x]$$
It can be shown that $g(t,x)$ is smooth and thus we can apply Itô.

In the case of american options we can exercise whenver we want. Let $\Phi(s,X_s)$ be the value if the option is exercised at time $s$. 
The generic price-formula for an american type option is given by

$$v(t,x)=\sup_{t\leq \tau \leq T}\mathbb{E}[\Phi(\tau,X_\tau)|X_t=x] $$

Due to the supremum one can no longer simpli apply Itô directly to $v(t,X_t)$. There are some cases where the $\sup$ of a function will also be smooth but that must not necessarily be the case.

Comment: Probilitator: Can you give a reference for the smoothness result for $g(t,x)$? I was just looking for something in that direction.

Comment: @gg I will have to look through my text-books. The last time I looked for it, it did take me a while to find the proof. The argument is however trivial if you assume $h$ to be bounded  - would this suffice to meet your needs ?